# Determine if a point is in a hyperellipsoid

Tags: geometry

I'm implementing an algorithm for a scientific application that requires determining if a set of points is inside an n-dimensional ellipsoid (hyper-ellipsoid). I have this working for the 2-d and 3-d cases, but I am not sure of how to proceed for cases of 4 or more dimensions.

Can a hyper-ellipsoid of n-dimensions be treated as a set of all the unique 3-d ellipsoid combinations?

This seems like it would not be the case given that two ellipses in 3-dimensions (each sharing a dimension) do not include all the points of the 3-d ellipsoid that covers their boundaries.

For the 3-d case, I am using the criterion:
$$
\left( {x \over a} \right) ^2 + \left({y \over b}\right) ^2 + \left({z \over c}\right) ^2 \le 1
$$

for inclusion, where:

- a, b, and c are the half-lengths of the ellipsoid's axes
- x, y, and z are the coordinates of a point

Note: In this implementation, points on the surface are counted as inside the ellipsoid.

Comment: Is there anything stopping you from using an inequality like $\left(\dfrac{x}{a}\right)^{\!2}+\left(\dfrac{y}{b}\right)^{\!2}+\left(\dfrac{z}{c}\right)^{\!2}+\left(\dfrac{w}{d}\right)^{\!2}\le 1?$

Comment: @AdrianKeister Thanks, does the pattern of summing these squares hold true for n-dimenstions?

Comment: Yep! It's what we call Euclidean distance, and it generalizes to $n$ dimensions.

Comment: Excellent, that's easy then. If you add this as an answer, I'll accept. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Euclidean distance and generalize the formula you already have:
$$\left(\dfrac{x}{a}\right)^{\!2}+\left(\dfrac{y}{b}\right)^{\!2}+\left(\dfrac{z}{c}\right)^{\!2}+\left(\dfrac{w}{d}\right)^{\!2}\le 1.$$
More dimensions will simply add more terms: variable squared over half-axis-lengths squared.