# Determine if a point is in a rotated hyperellipsoid

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3093688/determine-if-a-point-is-in-a-hyperellipsoid) a few days ago. I am implementing an algorithm to test whether a set of points is within an hyper-ellipsoid (HE). That post provided the correct answer for a non-rotated HE centered at the origin. However, I need a solution for an HE that is not at the origin and may be rotated in any dimension.

So, either I rotate all my data points (I assume, relative to the center of the HE?) or I account for the position and rotation of the HE. In either case, I am unsure of how to proceed.

From the answer to my previous question I get that there is a pattern that generalizes to n-dimensions:

$$
\left( {x \over a} \right) ^2 + \left({y \over b}\right) ^2 + \left({z \over c}\right) ^2 + \ldots \left( {n \over d_n }\right) ^2 \le 1
$$

And, after a bit more research, I see for the 2-dimensional case that rotations and translations can be accounted for by the following:

$$
\cfrac{
  \left(
    \cos (\alpha)(x_p - x_0) +
    \sin (\alpha)(y_p - y_0)
  \right)^2
}{a^2} +
\cfrac{
  \left(
    \sin (\alpha)(x_p - x_0) -
    \cos (\alpha)(y_p - y_0)
  \right)^2
}{b^2}
\le 1
$$

where:

- $x_p$, $y_p$ are the data point coordinates
- $x_0$, $y_0$ are the coordinates of the HE center
- $\alpha$ is the rotation angle in x, y of the HE
- $a$, $b$ are the half-length axes of the HE

So, how does this generalize to the n-dimensional case? Is there a similar predictable pattern that emerges in the trigonometry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, rewrite your original test slightly as $${x_1^2\over a_1^2}+\cdots+{x_n^2\over a_n^2}-1\le0.$$ Any orientation-preserving affine transformation will preserve the direction of the inequality, so you can either transform all of your points into this “standard” coordinate system and test them against this relatively simple inequality or transform the ellipsoid into the coordinate system of the data and test the points against a potentially more complex expression. I suspect that doing the former will be more efficient.

As for how to transform the equation of the ellipsoid, it’s easiest for me to describe in matrix form. Any quadric can be expressed by an equation of the form $\mathbf x^TQ\mathbf x=0$, where $Q$ is a symmetric matrix and $\mathbf x^T=(x_1,\dots,x_n,1)$. Under the point transformation $\mathbf x'=M\mathbf x$, substituting for $\mathbf x$ gives $(M^{-1}\mathbf x')^TQ(M^{-1}\mathbf x')={\mathbf x'}^T(M^{-T}QM^{-1})\mathbf x'$, so the matrix of the transformed quadric is $Q'=M^{-T}QM^{-1}$. For your application, the standardized ellipsoid that you’d be starting with has the matrix $Q = \operatorname{diag}(1/a_1^2,\dots,1/a_n^2,-1)$.

Comment: Thanks! One more clarification...the ellipsoids are defined as a set of center co-ords w/ a covariance matrix. My plan: 1) Get the half-lengths from the eigenvalues to construct the non-rotated ellipsoid at the origin. 2) Translate the data points by the center coordinates. 3) Apply the inverse of the covariance to the points. 4) Do the inequality check you've given. Does that sound correct?

Comment: @Fiver Not quite. You’re going to need the principal components (axes) of the ellipsoid in order to construct the correct rotation. Inverting the covariance matrix produces the dual to the ellipsoid, which is not at all what you want for this.

Comment: Does the eigenvector provide the principal components? If not, how do I derive them?

Comment: @Fiver Yes, though if there are repeated eigenvalues you might need to orthogonalize.

Comment: Got it, it's working now for n-dimensions! Thank you!